# How to insert data into many-to-many tables using SQLAlchemy+asyncpg

Tags: postgresql

I have tables in fastapi app with relationship "many-to-many"

```
class ShopCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "shop_category"
    shop_id: int = Column(ForeignKey("shop.id", ondelete="cascade"), primary_key=True)
    category_id: int = Column(ForeignKey("category.id", ondelete="cascade"), primary_key=True)

class Shop(Base):
    __tablename__ = "shop"
    id: Optional[int] = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Column(String(length=50), unique=True)
    categories: List["Category"] = relationship("Category",
                                                secondary="shop_category",
                                                back_populates="shops")

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category"
    id: Optional[int] = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Column(String(length=40), unique=True)
    shops: List[Shop] = relationship("Shop",
                                     secondary="shop_category",
                                     back_populates="categories",
                                     lazy="joined")
```

I want to insert data into these tables in one query using sqlalchemy and asyncpg.

Here is the data

```
{ "name": "shop1",
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "category1",
      "id": 22
    },
    {
      "name": "category2",
      "id": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote a function to insert data into the tables in one query for me

```
async def add_shop(new_shop: ShopCreate,
                   session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):

    new_shop_dict = new_shop.dict()
    categories = new_shop_dict.pop('categories')
    category_list = []
    for category in categories:
        category_list.append(Category(**category)) 
    stmt = insert(Shop).values(**new_shop_dict, categories=category_list)
    await session.execute(stmt)
    await session.commit()
    return {"status": "ok"}
```

But it doesn't work.
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: categories
Why doesn't he see the categories?
What to do with it?
Help me, please!

Comment: Try `categories : Mapped[List[Category]] = ...` the columns should be of type `Mapped`